# Populate NUXTJS Store state content on startup?

Tags: nuxt.js, state, vuex, nuxtjs

I want my Nuxtjs store state (`ssr: false`, so no `nuxtServerInit`) with data when a user starts the application.

The goal is to make a date calculation on startup and store the answer on nuxtjs store, so when I need this information I do not need to recalculate again everytime (this information will be used on many pages).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a small plugin which will run on startup and can call a store action for you, similar to `nuxtServerInit`.

```js
// ~/plugins/nuxtClientInit.js

export default async function (context) {
  await context.store.dispatch('nuxtClientInit', context)
}
```

Then simply add it to your `nuxt.config.js`.

```js
...

plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/nuxtClientInit.js', mode: 'client' }
],

...
```

Now the `nuxtClientInit` store action will be called at startup, you can even access the context object.

```js
actions: {
  nuxtClientInit ({ commit }, context) {
    // commit(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for what I asked. Thank you.
But (i don't know why) I cannot access methods that I define as plugins through this.$myMethod. When I do the same with others store's actions, works fine, but in this nuxtClientInit, $myMethod is undefined. Any idea?

Comment: Normally you can access the context through `this`, but in this special action you need to access it through the `context` object you get as parameter. So use `context.$myMethod` instead of `this.$myMethod` and it should work.

If that doesn't work, it could also be that the order in which you add your plugins matter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You were right @florian-pallas. The order matters. I reorder the plugins list so `{ src: '~/plugins/nuxtClientInit.js', mode: 'client' }` is the last one to load and now it's working fine :) Thanks